# Uncaught Error: Script error for "aws-sdk"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Trying to use the AWS SDK for node but I get this error Uncaught Error: Script error for "aws-sdk"
Heres my code. I tried using require('aws-sdk'), but the console error than said to use require([],()=>{})
I downloaded both require and aws-sdk from npm

```
require(['aws-sdk'], (AWS) => {
    let email = document.getElementById('footerEmail');
    let emailSubmit = document.getElementById('footerButton');
    AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });


    let sns = new AWS.SNS();

    let params = {
        Protocol: 'email', /* required */
        TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:274999247491:HouseRoots', /* required */
        Endpoint: email.value,
        ReturnSubscriptionArn: false
    };
    console.log('h');
    emailSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('h');
        sns.subscribe(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                email.value = "error occured";
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                email.value = "confirmation sent";
            }
        });
        console.log('h');
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you use AWS sdk in the client side?

Comment: trying to register subscriber to sns topic

Comment: you must do it from the server side and configure you aws credentials.

Comment: im using node, and my aws credentials are in ~/.aws/

Comment: please checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

I prepare you a basic sample app, [press here](https://github.com/ns4lin4s/stackoverflow/tree/master/54993479).

**For run:**

- npm install
- node app.js
- open browser localhost:3000/

**You must have pre-configured:**

- aws_credentials file
- you must change region in app.js (***AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});***)
- the user must have to access SNS

  [image]

Flow:

[image]