# Accessing amazon resources using javascript sdk without providing accesskey and secretkey

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-organizations

Currently I am accessing amazon organisation service using below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AWS SDK for JavaScript - Sample Application</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/aws-sdk-2.417.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var params = {}
        AWS.config.update({
                region: 'us-east-1',
                accessKeyId: '***********',
                secretAccessKey: '*************'
            });
        var organizations = new AWS.Organizations();
        organizations.listAccounts(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else            // successful response
                var accts = []
                console.log(data)
                $('#results').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
                for(var i = 0; i < data['Accounts'].length; i++) { 
                      $("#newList").append("<li>"+ data['Accounts'][i]['Id'] + ":" + data['Accounts'][i]['Name']+"</li>");

                  accts.push({"id": data['Accounts'][i]['Id'], "name": data['Accounts'][i]['Name']});
                }
              console.log(accts);
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my production system, is there a way customer can log in using their AWS account there and then without the intake of access key and secret key ?

Comment: you must use aws-sdk from server, this dev also had the same problem.. here link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993479/uncaught-error-script-error-for-aws-sdk/54995018#54995018

Comment: I want to access the customer's account, so the access credentials should be of the customer. It has to be done on the web page. Either by providing credentials or by sso equivalent behavior.

Comment: You probably want to head in the Assume Role direction... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html

Comment: @nishantpathak you take AWS access key and secret key as inputs from your customer and perform this

Answer (score 0):

use HTML input tags to get input from HTML tags and initialize those variable with customer input.
have a button to trigger initialization after customer enter values

```
acesskey : <input type="password" id="acesskey">
secretkey : <input type="password; id="secretkey">
<button type="button" onclick="<jsfunction>" >
```

in js code, you can initialize variables
as bellow

```
var acesskey = document.getElementById("acesskey").value;
var secretkey = document.getElementById("secretkey").value;
```

pass these values to aws.config.update function

Comment: I do not want to ask for intake of access key and secret key. Customer are not comfortable in sharing that.

Comment: you don't take it. you will get it from user input and forward those values to aws lib

Comment: @rohitcoder Have you read this lines in Question
"In my production system, is there a way customer can log in using their aws account there "

Comment: @nishantpathak but you have written "is there a way customer can log in using their AWS account there". are you looking for SSO ?